# Oracle : Use of CURSOR%FOUND in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a code as follows.

My question is - why do we need IF statement for CURSOR%FOUND ?

If no rows are found, that will trigger NO_DATA_FOUND condition and control will automatically go to the EXCEPTION block.

Correct ?

begin

```
OPEN l_cursor;
LOOP
  FETCH l_cursor into l_rec;
  
  if ( l_cursor%FOUND ) then
      do something
  else
      do_something_else;
  end if;
  
END LOOP;

CLOSE l_cursor

EXCEPTION
   WHEN no_data_found then
     ...
END;
```

Comment: The reason is really about control.  You have one exception block, but could have multiple sections of code, so by testing in the code, you can handle the condition without having to jump control down to your exception block, and so you can continue on through other pieces of code.

Comment: Nope.  explicit cursor will not trigger an exception.  SELECT ... INTO ... will trigger NO_DATA_FOUND. See here - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/fetch_statement.htm

Comment: Why don't you try it. ```SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE 1 = 2``` will return no rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
OPEN l_cursor;
LOOP     
  FETCH l_cursor into l_rec;
  EXIT WHEN l_cursor%NOTFOUND;
  ...do something...
END LOOP;
CLOSE l_cursor;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN no_data_found then
     ...
END;
```

Comment: LOOP ...  END LOOP is indefinite, so you have to make an exit either your way where in ELSE clause you should have EXIT command or use the opposite criteria like in this answer with EXIT WHEN Cursor%NOTFOUND command so you don't need If...Else... at all.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: As  already mentioned, in PL/SQL the ordinary SELECT fld INTO var... will raise NO_DATA_FOUND exception. On the other side FETCH Cursor INTO var... will not raise such an exception but it will attach the NOTFOUND status to the Cursor. That status, in case we are looping Cursor in an indefinite loop, should be checked either along with EXIT command (as it is in thiis answer) or using some  other methid like it was IF...ELSE... stated in the question in wich case is mandatory to make an EXIT the indefinite LOOP. Exception will not be of any help here.